# geojson file doesn't plot points on mapbox in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am running jupyter notebook on Databricks and attempting to render a map. I tried the example from the documentation to test and it doesn't plot the points.

```
import mapboxgl
from mapboxgl.viz import *
from mapboxgl.utils import df_to_geojson
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js'></script>"))



# Load data from sample csv
data_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapbox/mapboxgl-jupyter/master/examples/data/points.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_url)

# Must be a public token, starting with `pk`
token = mapbox_token

# Create a geojson file export from a Pandas dataframe
df_to_geojson(df, filename='points.geojson',
              properties=['Avg Medicare Payments', 'Avg Covered Charges', 'date'],
              lat='lat', lon='lon', precision=3)

# Generate data breaks and color stops from colorBrewer
color_breaks = [0,10,100,1000,10000]
color_stops = create_color_stops(color_breaks, colors='YlGnBu')

# Create the viz from the dataframe
viz = CircleViz('points.geojson',
                access_token=token,
                height='400px',
                color_property = "Avg Medicare Payments",
                color_stops = color_stops,
                center = (-95, 40),
                zoom = 3,
                below_layer = 'waterway-label'
              )
viz.show()
```

[image: mapbox]